# Why Python datatypes behave like this in Python prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, read-eval-print-loop

While messing around with python in the terminal I noticed something strange. If you enter an expression such as `1+2*3`, the terminal will output 7, which is strange as this shouldn't print anything but it does. But then if you use a function such as print("hello world"), it will output `hello world`, and not `None`, which is what print returns. Also, typing `True` outputs `True`, and `False` outputs `False`, but typing `None` does not output anything. How does python decide when to output a value?

Comment: The interactive session is a REPL. It reads, evaluates, prints, and loops.

Comment: @brittenb what are you confused about?

Comment: Python terminal is not python language.

Comment: The REPL evaluates and prints the results of expressions and the output side effects of any functions you call.

Comment: Further,  it uses a special case for `None` where if `None` is the value of your last expression, it prints the empty string.

Comment: @MichaelO. how is python in the terminal not python?

Comment: @DanielGee: if you run an interactive session, the behavior will be slightly different: if you run `python file.py`, it will *not* display intermediate expression results.

Comment: I think @brittenb was surprised that this was described as strange behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see is a Python REPL (Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop).

Most of the REPLs (including Python's REPL) will use an *online parser*: a parser that builds an expression tree. From the moment the expression tree is built, the REPL will *evaluate it* (this can be a function defintion, in which case the function is parsed and analyzed). After evaluating, the REPL will obtain the result and **inspect the result***. If it is **`None`, the result is not printed**. The same happens with assignments by the way.

For example:

```
>>> None  # None is not printed
>>> a = 2 # assignments are not printed
>>>
```

In case the result is *not* `None`, then it will call the `repr(..)` builtin method, and thus print the *textual representation* of the result.

Comment: This is the case for toplevel expressions, you can enter, say, definitions or block statements in which function calls are not evaluated at entry at all.

Comment: @pvg: well they are evaluated in the sense that Python reads a `def x...` and thus will construct a syntax tree. But of course, like when you load a file in Python, a function is not evaluated. That would be weird, since Python cannot know what parameters are valid.

Comment: They are parsed, not evaluated. If you type `if exit(0):` the interpreter doesn't instantly exit.

Comment: @pvg: yes because there is an opening indentation part.

Comment: Because it's not an expression. The behaviour you are describing applies to expressions.

Comment: @pvg: at that stage it is indeed not an expression yet, since there are some tokens on the parser stack.

Comment: It's never an expression. It's a statement.

Comment: @pvg: for an online stack-based context-free parser, that is the same.

Answer (score 8):

Exactly what happens when you evaluate an expression is determined by `sys.displayhook`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook):

> **`sys.displayhook(value)`**
>
> If `value` is not `None`, this function prints it to `sys.stdout`, and saves it in `__builtin__._`.
>
> `sys.displayhook` is called on the result of evaluating an expression entered in an interactive Python session. The display of these values can be customized by assigning another one-argument function to `sys.displayhook`.

Example of a simple override which takes away the `None` special case:

```
>>> def new_hook(x):
...   print(repr(x))
...   
>>> sys.displayhook = new_hook
>>> 3
3
>>> None
None
```

Comment: Nice answer Alex !

Answer (score 3):

The python session in the terminal is known as  REPL, or Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop, which takes in input, evaluates it and returns the result. Check out the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).